# Send something through Serial even with Processing minimized

Tags: serial-port, arduino, processing

I'm currently working with a little car that responds to the same movements than the car from a PC game but I'm having a little problem involving Processing and Serial input/output. I made a script that catches what key was pressed, send it to the Arduino through Serial I/O and the arduino controls some motors according to the expected movements but it only works when the Processing software/window is open. Is there anyway to make it work even with the Processing software/window minimized?

I want to keep the game in fullscreen mode and I want that the information about which key was pressed arrives to the game(it is what will control the game) and to the processing software(that will send it to Arduino). How can I do this?

Thank you.

Comment: 2 Comments. 1st This solution will depend on the system you are on and how the OS publishes commands to nonactive programs 2nd you could probably do this by combing the two programs. Can you be more specific about the different parts of your program and what language everything is written in?

Comment: Tried to run your processing program exported as an .exe file (if you are running under Windows)?